# layout folder name for devices 720x1280 like samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, android-layout

I made an app earlier which was all good, at the time of development there were only two devices in the market galaxy note and samsung nexus, now devices with resolution 720*1280 are around 30, when my app runs on these devices they go to left corner leaving the empty space behind, layout folder name were created were layout-small, layout-large, layout-normal,

As far I know xlarge is for tablets, my question is what will be the layout folder name for devices having 720*1280 resolution, and what dpi in width they have, like in normal screen the width is 320dp , what will be in hd devices.

**Edit :** another thing sw360dp works fine on ICS, jelly beans does not pick resources from it. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using folder name with /layout-sw360dp/  and width 360dp

Comment: i have sw360dp but it;s not getting used by S3

Comment: please tel us how do you calculate this ?

Answer (score 3):

For devices having 720 * 1280 resolution, you can use `layout-sw720dp` folder

More info is provided in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) (see Configuration Examples)

> To help you target some of your designs for different types of
>   devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:
>
> - 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800    hdpi, etc).
> - 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
> - 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
> - 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
>
> For other cases in which you want to further customize your UI to
>   differentiate between sizes such as 7” and 10” tablets, you can define
>   additional smallest width layouts:
>
> - res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than    600dp available width)
> - res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide    and bigger)
> - res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide    and bigger)

Comment: yeah.. its given in the table on you see in official documentation

Comment: The Galaxy S3 is a xhdpi device, so you have to divide a pixel-based dimension by 2 to get the dimension in dp. So the S3 is 640dp tall, and 360dp wide.